# How do I plot a trajectory on a 2d map given lat lon data

Tags: matlab, plot, maps, mapping

I have lat lon data for a rocket trajectory and I want to plot it onto a 2d map of the US.

I have tried plotting it using geoshow() but the data wont stick onto the map, even after using 
`hold on;`

```
% Florida map axes
figure; ax = usamap('florida');
setm(ax, 'FFaceColor', [.5 .7 .9])
title('Florida map')

% read shapefile of US states with names and locations
states = geoshape(shaperead('usastatehi.shp', 'UseGeoCoords', true));

% display map
geoshow(states, 'Parent',ax); hold on;
% plot(data.long,data.gdlat)  method 1
% plotm(data.long,data.gdlat) method 2
% linem(data.long,data.gdlat) method 3
```

Expected result is to have a trajectory from central florida towards the atlantic plotted onto the map of florida.

Comment: Can you try reversing the order of latitude and longitude? [plotm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/plotm.html) should be `plotm(lat,lon)`

Comment: Ahh thats it! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to utilize a satellite photo? Do I need an shp file for that or is it already apart of the available ones?

Comment: Tbh, I've never worked with MATLAB mapping toolbox before. From looking at the output of the shaperead function, there doesn't seem to be any information about "imagery," just a pointset for the outline of Florida.

I think you need to try a different approach if you want a satellite photo background.